# Adding custom tpl.php file for a new or edit node content

Tags: forms

I am having issues with overriding the "add form" for a content type with a tpl.php file. The following works fine when its not an "add form".  Any advice? Here is what is in my hook_theme function.  And I have a data-set-node-form.tpl.php file in the /templates file with my html.

```
$items['data_set_node_form'] = array(
  'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
  'render element' => 'form',
  'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'bootstrap_subtheme') . '/templates',
  'template' => 'data-set-node-form',
);
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Which template exactly are you trying to override? Page template - `page.tpl.php` - or something else?

Comment: I want to reformat the edit form for a custom content type I created.  It seems the

Comment: Ok, I figured it out, I had a different theme set for the administration them! Once I changed it, everything works as it should.